# UI mobile framework that plays well with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, mobile, user-interface, backbone.js

I'd like to find an UI mobile framework to use along with Backbone. I like jQuery Mobile and it's way of structuring the HTML code, it's easy to build a multipage application in a single HTML with an acceptable design. However, jQuery Mobile is more than an UI framework, as it handles more stuff like routing, something that doesn't play very well with Backbone. Besides, it's a bit heavy, and the performance in mobile devices is not really good.
So, basically, I'm looking for a light framework that styles headers, footers, buttons, list views, etc., and handles page transitions. Does that exist?

Comment: I haven't used it myself but you might want to check out [jqmobi](http://www.jqmobi.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I have found [Lungo](http://lungo.tapquo.com/). The design is very clean and good looking, and it takes advantage of a number of HTML5 features. The downside (if it is a downside) is that requires [Quo](http://quojs.tapquo.com/), another library of the same company, to traverse the DOM and handle touch events. However, I'm used to jQuery, and the former lacks some features that are included in jQuery, so I ended up with two libraries that have pretty much the same purpose.

Comment: How did you get on getting Lungo playing with Backbone? I am just trying this but at a bit of a loss on where to start. (Currently have a backbone + jquerymobile app, and looking for a replacement to kick out jqm).

Comment: @Meirion I just developed a small test, but everything looks alright. There was a small problem with the pages navigation but seems to be solved in the new version of Lungo. Very promising framework, it's easy to use, you should check the docs out http://lungo.tapquo.com/howto/core/ http://lungo.tapquo.com/howto/prototype/

Comment: Sounds good. I started making a static prototype app with Lungo and sticking to their provided components worked well. Things got a bit hairy when I tried to stray from their standard pattern of headers and nav bars etc.  May I ask, have you had to add Jquery (in addition to QuoJS) in order for Backbone's dom selectors to work?

Comment: @Meirion Yep, I had to. That's one of the downsides I found in Lungo: it requires QuoJS. So, as jQuery is needed by Backbone, you end up with two libraries for almost the same purpose. I'm considering trying Zepto

Comment: With backbone, ideally you should be doing much DOM manipulation, so I bet you could provide a custom `Backbone.$` implementation based on QuoJS

Comment: Lungo does its own routing. Can you disable that in favor of a Backbone router?

Answer (score 1):

Although you ruled out jQuery Mobile in the first line of your question, one of the Backbone "boilerplate" packages I've seen does use jQuery Mobile by turning off the routing, so that you can still use the Backbone router,:

```
// Prevents all jQuery Mobile anchor click handling
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
// Prevents jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

So it might still be worth a try if you don't find anything else. Check out the [Backbone-Require-Boilerplate project](https://github.com/gfranko/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate), it has a whole system to split up the Desktop and Mobile versions of a Backbone app using conditional Require.js loaders - quite interesting.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I'm looking for something lighter than jQM. I don't need something very complex, just a library that applies some basic styling and handles page transitions. I already tried jQM+Backbone, but it gave me some problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327798/backbone-urls-hash-becomes-empty-on-orientation-change)

Comment: Ah, interesting issue with the orientation... well best of luck on your search, I'll be interested to hear if you find something that works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at junior? http://justspamjustin.github.io/junior/

It seems to be pretty lightweight, at least in terms of integrating with backbone.